# How to show sorting arrow in SPGridView

Tags: 2010, visual-web-part, spgridview, sorting

I have an SPGridView control in a visual web part. I am trying to implement sorting functionality, but the grid control is not displaying the sorting arrow next to each column header. **How can the sorting arrow be enabled ?**

**SPGridViewControl**

```
<SharePoint:SPGridView ID="ShowNode" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
        AllowSorting="true" ShowHeader="true" ShowFooter="true" OnRowDataBound="ShowNode_RowDataBound" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ShowNode_RowIndexChanged" OnSorting="ShowNode_Sort" OnRowCommand="ShowNode_RowClick">
<Columns>
<%--<asp:HyperLinkField HeaderText="Name" DataTextField="Title" />--%>
<asp:ImageField HeaderText="Icon"  DataImageUrlField="Img" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"></asp:ImageField>
<SharePoint:SPBoundField HeaderText="Name" DataField="Title" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" SortExpression="Name"/>
<SharePoint:SPBoundField HeaderText="Type" DataField="Type" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" SortExpression="Type" />
<asp:HyperLinkField  DataTextField="Link" HeaderText="Link" Visible="false" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"/>
</Columns>
</SharePoint:SPGridView>
```